# How to split backslash in c#

Tags: c#, string, split

I want to split a string using the '\' , Is there a way to split using back slash?

```
//For example...
string number = "[\"1\",\"4\"]";
output 1,4
```

Comment: Did you even google? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: \ is not a literal here, but an escape letter, what you might wish is to split with "

Comment: the backslash in your example is an escape character. It allows you to display the `"` inside your string. you cannot split by it, because technically it is not part of your string

Comment: `number` is a string that contains `["1","4"]`, no slashes

Comment: if one of the answers helped you to solve the problem, you might consider to mark it as accepted. If you don't know how to do it [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) might help. happy coding

Answer (score 1):

The backslash in your example is an escape character. It allows you to display the " inside your string. you cannot split by it, because technically it is not part of your string.

To get the output that you want you need to remove everything else. You can use [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) for it:

```
string number = "[\"1\",\"4\"]";
string output = Regex.Replace(number, "[\\[\"\\]]", "");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

You can do it also without regex with the given string methods:

```
string output = number.TrimStart('[').Replace("\"", "").TrimEnd(']');
```

Output:

> `1,4`

Here is the [entire list of escape sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) for further information.